# Change language on SAP shortcut

Tags: sap-gui

I got a link on my desktop. Selecting this, my computer is opening a connection to an SAP System - SingleSignOn, so no user and password is required. The link looks like this (I changed the parameter like server, client etc.):

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe" /shortcut="-sid=R56 -client=054 -snc_qop=7 -snc_name=p/secude:CN=link@LING.NET -gui=/H/saprouter.bus.link.net/M/123456.bus.link.net/S/3600/G/Logistik"`

This is working quite fine. But now, I want him to logon using the german language. I read about that and found out, that the parameter is LANG=DE but where do I have to place it? I tried `-lang=de` and got no satisfying result.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: is your SAP installation prepared for a german logon? Administrators have to explicitly allow logon languages in the application server configuration. According to the SAP wiki, the parameter should be -language=DE : https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/NWTech/SAPshortcut

Comment: Thank you - thats it. -language=DE solved my problem.

Comment: good to hear, I added it as an answer.

Comment: @Jan021981, so mark this as answer if it solved your problem, encourage people to give more useful answers

Answer (score 2):

According to the [SAP Wiki](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/NWTech/SAPshortcut), the parameter for the logon shortcut should be `-language=DE`.

Not relevant for this particular question, but I just want to add that the system administrator for the SAP system has to explicitly allow logon languages in the application server configuration (in addition to uploading the necessary language packages). Creating a shortcut with an unsupported language for that particular logon server/group will likely result in an error message.